# how to use ftp on amazon aws

Tags: ftp, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Today is my second day of trying to use amazon and i have started to pull my hairs. I want to set up ftp with amazon. I have signed up with them and and created an instance with amazon EC2. I have downloaded the key and I am able to login with ssh using the through Terminal in my mac. I can create files in the instance through terminal.
The instance is something like following:
 Public DNS: ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com

I have created a index.html file at this location via terminal. But I am not able to view it in the browser using following url:
ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/index.html
I just want to create web services here which I will be using in iPhone.

Also I am not sure how to go forward. How will I get to my local files and upload them to server. In other ftps I could do it using lcd, get, put etc but these commands are not working here. can some one please help me how should I go ahead because at this moment I am just banging my head to wall. Someone please help me.

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: I assume you have opened the correct ports in the servers associated security group?

Comment: can you please elaborate me more on it? What should I have there so that I can use it as ftp. I have not used any ports yet.

Comment: When you created the instance, you would have specified a security group. Under the ec2 tab of the aws management portal, you need to to open inbound ports to your instance (within the appropriate security group). You can do this via the commend line if necessary, but if you not familiar stick to the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 2014/11/20**

Dmitry Leskov is actually the better one. You should use his approach.

**Answer from 2012**

You first have to setup a LAMP (Linux, Apache, mySQL, PHP) stack on your EC2 instance to run any kind of web service.

This means you have to go trough the following steps:

- Create an EC2 instance
- Setup EBS Storage for mySQL data
- Install mySQL
- Configure mySQL
- Install Apache
- Configure Apache
- Install PHP
- Configure PHP

If you need a detailed instruction, I'd recommend you to take a look at this: [Building EC2 with LAMP](http://jonathanhui.com/building-ec2-amazon-linux-lamp).

To transfer files to your EC2 instance you can use any FTP client, which supports SFTP and key pairs (you can also enable `PasswordAuthentication` for SSH to login with credentials). I'm using Transmit with no problems.

Comment: You don't need LAMP to run a web service. You need an OS and a web server. Linux, Apache, mySQL and PHP are all optional. I, for one, am happy using nginx, python and postgres.

Comment: @micapam: This answer is more than two years old. And at the time of writing it was my answer to the question asked, which was accepted by pankaj.

Answer (score 8):

Use scp to copy files over ssh:

`scp -i key-pair-file file-to-upload ec2-user@instance-public-DNS:`

Notice the colon at the end!

With plain EC2 instances, you also need to install some sort of Web server software to power your Web service, and open the HTTP port in the firewall.

Just in case you plan to write your Web service in Java, I have put together a series of articles (**[Part I](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/tomcat-amazon-ec2-basic.html)**, **[Part II](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/tomcat-amazon-ec2-java-stack.html)**, **[Part III](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/tomcat-amazon-ec2-advanced.html)**) guiding through the basics of installing Apache Tomcat on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance.

Comment: yesterday it was working fine but today when I am trying to connect with amazon in similar way by using the private key, i am getting it as timed out. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: I think you must have restarted your instance. If so, its IP address and hence public DNS have changed. Assign an Elastic IP address to your instance to avoid that problem in the future.

Comment: This worked with the .ppk version of my key-pair-file, rather than the .pem.

Comment: @TomDestry Aren't you using pscp that comes with PuTTY?

Answer (score -1):

On a related note, I encountered a strange problem where I could not FTP from a PHP script running under apache - but I could if I ran the PHP script as root from the command line.  After a day of googling, I found this, which solved the problem.

Disable SELinux. (Security Enhanced Linux) 
The temporary solution is:

echo 0 >/selinux/enforce

..which will prove the concept, but will not survive a reboot. There are plenty of resources out there that describe how to permanently disable SELinux.