# Is a LAMP stack necessary on aws for a FTP server?

Tags: ftp, amazon-web-services, lamp

I would like to setup an ftp site on AWS/EC2 and I have read in more than one that LAMP is recommended (including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484062/how-to-use-ftp-on-amazon-aws) and don't understand why I need PHP and mySQL for an FTP site.

Comment: You don't need that stuff.  You do need a FTP server and to open the appropriate ports on your firewall and security group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **do *not* need** a LAMP stack and I would strongly advice against its installation. A usual security rule is to run only as much software as required.

That you need is a FTP server. Install Ubuntu and configure FTP server as [described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html), for instance. Alternatively you can choose some other from many available FTP servers, free and commercial.